# Retrieve image from stream mp3 url

Tags: android, stream, mp3, exoplayer

I have tried to retrieve album image from stream mp3 url but I did not find any thing working with stream url all of the solutions works with local mp3 only such like

```
  MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
        mmr.setDataSource("http://listen.livestreamingservice.com/181-beatles_128k.mp3", new HashMap<String, String>());
    else
        mmr.setDataSource("http://listen.livestreamingservice.com/181-beatles_128k.mp3");


    byte[] artBytes = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
    if (artBytes != null) {
        //     InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(artBytes, 0, artBytes.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
    }
```

**I tried also ExoPlayer:**

```
 player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            for (int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++) {
                TrackGroup trackGroup = trackGroups.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < trackGroup.length; j++) {
                    Metadata trackMetadata = trackGroup.getFormat(j).metadata;
                    if (trackMetadata != null) {
                        // We found metadata. Do something with it here!
                    }
                }
            }
            super.onTracksChanged(trackGroups, trackSelections);

        }
    });
    /////
```

But I could not know how to get the image or artwork.

Is there is any way to fetch the image from stream mp3 url, Please help me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pskink Could you please explain more how to implement 
setDataSource(FileDescriptor)

Comment: That shown link doesn't have any image embedded inside the mp3 file (bytes).

Comment: Thank you, Could you please provide me with mp3 link which includes embedded image?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have such links. Maybe make your own mp3 file (use a tool to add artwork) and put online to test.